# TS2722: Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined' on a well-defined & readonly function

Tags: typescript, function, undefined

I just stumbled upon this:

```
type Author = {
    readonly getName?: () => string;
}

const john: Author = {
    getName: () => 'John Doe',
};

john.getName();  // TS2722: Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'
```

- the code clearly defines the `john.getName` function
- since `getName` is readonly, it cannot be modified & set to `undefined`

but TypeScript doesn't seem to agree.

I know I could use one of these:

```
john.getName!();
john.getName?.();
john.getName && john.getName();
```

but I have no clue to why this would be needed in this case.

Is there a way to avoid those ugly workarounds?

Comment: You annotated `john` as `Author` so that's what the compiler believes; `getName` is optional and could be `undefined`.  If you don't want that behavior you shouldn't annotate; you could use `satisfies` instead, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/WzkP1w).  Does that fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I read about `satisfies` when it came out but forgot about it. Putting the type at the end hurts readability imho, but this seems the way to do it and it makes sense. Feel free to post an answer and I'll gladly accept it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) with a (non-[union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types)) type, you've essentially told the compiler to ignore any more specific information it might be able to infer from the initializing value.  In

```
type Author = {
  readonly getName?: () => string;
}

const john: Author = {
  getName: () => 'John Doe',
};
```

The compiler only knows that `john` is of type `Author`, and therefore its `getName` property is [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) and might be `undefined`:

```
  john.getName();  // error
```

---

One approach therefore is to leave off the annotation and let the compiler infer the type of the variable from the initializer:

```
const john = {
  getName: () => 'John Doe',
};
john.getName();  // okay
```

This doesn't ensure that `john` is compatible with `Author`, though, which is presumably why you annotated it as such originally:

```
const john = {
  getName: () => 123, // <-- no error
}
```

You can rectify this by using [the `satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) instead of an annotation, so you're warned about any mismatches:

```
const john = {
  getName: () => 123, // <-- error!
  //~~~~~ <-- Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'
} satisfies Author
```

and you can fix them:

```
const john = {
  getName: () => 'John Doe',
} satisfies Author // okay
```

---

Note that I specified that your problem happens when you annotate with a *non-union* type.  If you use a union type instead, then [assignment to the variable will narrow the apparent type of the variable](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#assignments).  If `Author` had instead been

```
type Author = {
  readonly getName: () => string;
} | {
  readonly getName?: never;
}
```

Then the following assignment

```
const john: Author = {
  getName: () => 'John Doe',
};
```

would give you the narrowing you presumably expected to happen in the first place:

```
john;
// ^? const john: { readonly getName: () => string; }

john.getName(); // okay
```

But such an approach relies on you refactoring your types so that they are unions, which has observable effects:

```
const w: { a: 1 | 2 } = { a: 1 }
w.a = 2; // okay

const x: { a: 1 } | { a: 2 } = { a: 1 }
x.a = 2; // error
```

So it might not be appropriate for every use case.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-WGqB9WESm6Fclyx4KtbVd7IADq-Bo8H4ADEaAAPaC-D29hFQ7P9YKkxEyZGTYcYk4Cj3455rH0eP3beGJ4ch06JPwXDLZL2dli6g3QPs2hGSCCAA1iAbDXv6Q7OiOTy5EwE4qkgqrADQCiaGKggAO4eow3Q7v2tpblIh6OkGWjPueeIdgAPoGDoouRLrEBAABuoqXt6bi3lB-gAXC+6SE+lJYmcb4AlcXr2IOwCXiySAAHraNxpq8fouCjKRjHCZiiw4niV4yTKhxlEBoHgZBvpIFh6l8voVJIHRNLPPCdlIA5ziSFhBT8uINK2GZYEQYSPHLrZID2S5dEaRFSDOY4rmxR5rjLj5IT+UBMYDgSjhAA)

Comment: Awesome answer. The part on union types is very interesting, I didn't think of this either. Thanks again!